# Automatically adjust content insets for views with custom a tab bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitabbarcontroller

I created a custom tab bar controller. It works very similar to `UITabBarController` but with a more advanced layout for the `UITabBar`.

How do I adjust the bottom content insets for views that appear in my custom tab bar controller? For instance if I show a `UITableView` in my custom tab bar controller I can manually adjust the content insets like this.

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 49, 0);
self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 49, 0);
```

However the problem gets more complicated if I push another view onto this table view like a collection view. Is there a way to get these views to automatically adjust their content insets like they do in the default `UITabBarController` implementation?

Comment: Did you subclass uitabbarcontroller?

Comment: No, it's a subclassed UIViewController.

Comment: One way would be to check in the parent controller, for the child controllers, if the views exists, then to provide contentInsets

Comment: Don't know if it will work but I would try to override [bottomLayoutGuide](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621504-bottomlayoutguide) in your custom tab bar controller

Comment: I haven't tried that but I'm not very familiar with auto layout. How would I set the up?

Comment: Are you using UIView, then, for your tab bar items, or are you at least subclassing `UITabBarItem` for those?

Comment: The custom tab bar itself is a UIScrollView subclass with custom UI that's sized the same dimensions as a `UITabBar`.

Answer (score 2):

We've recently done something similar in our app, and ended up simply having a container view that holds any content we're going to display in the controller. The advantage of this approach is that you can add whatever constraints you'd like to the container view (such as bottom padding between the container and the tab bar).

[Container view with bottom padding to tab bar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcsxE.png)

**Edit: Misunderstood the question**

You can simply check that the content view is able to setContentInset:

```
- (void)setContentInset:(UIEdgeInset)insets {

    if ([self.contentView respondsToSelector:@selector(setContentInset:)]) {
        [self.contentView setValue:insets forKey:@"contentInset"];
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with setting the content insets directly is that if you push a view onto this navigation controller the next view does not adopt these content insets. I don't understand how UITabBarController does this automatically.

Comment: Should still be pretty straight forward. Subclass navigation controller, overwrite `pushViewController:`, add a delegate method `willPushViewController:`, set tab bar controller as delegate of nav controller, then your tab bar controller just needs a way of determining if the view controller being pushed is able to set content insets, and if so, set them. You could, for example, define a protocol and ensure your VCs conform to it if they need to adjust insets.